# EKS Nodes not Registering in Target Group using ALB Ingress Controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I have followed the below AWS document to create an ALB ingress controller;

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-alb-ingress-controller-setup/

EKS:
version: 1.19

All the services are created successfully, with no errors.

But unfortunately, the nodes are not registered in the target groups of the ALB.

I also tried the alb ingress controller with a different version, but the same issue found.

used the example application;

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1.3/docs/examples/2048/2048_full.yaml
```

Output below;

Ingress -->

```
[centos@ip-10-1-68-249 alb-controller]$ kubectl get ing -n game-2048 -o wide
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
NAME           CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS                                                                   PORTS   AGE
ingress-2048   <none>   *       k8s-game2048-ingress2-253e697ad8-1355143956.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80      81s
```

TargetGroupBinding -->

```
[centos@ip-10-1-68-249 alb-controller]$ kubectl get TargetGroupBinding -n game-2048 -o wide
NAME                               SERVICE-NAME   SERVICE-PORT   TARGET-TYPE   ARN                                                                                                                 AGE
k8s-game2048-service2-3c0ccb9f36   service-2048   80             ip            arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:targetgroup/k8s-game2048-service2-3c0ccb9f36/faa10866343a792f   3m30s
```

but the instance is not attached to the target group;

[image]

Could anyone support here

Comment: What does the ALB ingress pod shows in its logs?

Comment: @mreferre, it's running. here the ingress is created the lb. the instance is not attaching

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same issue, just newer cluster version (1.22). The problem was with security group configuration for managed nodes.

First sign of trouble made itself apparent while browsing logs for the `aws-load-balancer-controller` pods

I noticed an error:

```
{"...","error":"expect exactly one securityGroup tagged with kubernetes.io/cluster/... for eni eni-0d46id..., got: [sg-081baacc1d925f936 sg-0a11d768e92737297]"}
```

This made me look at security group configuration. I noticed I attach the primary cluster group right to the nodes as well as their normal node-to-node group, which is excess.

Since I used `terraform` for the deployment and the official `aws-eks` module [1], I only had to remove this parameter from node group configuration:

```
attach_cluster_primary_security_group = true
```

Once deployed, and after rebooting the ingress controller, it automatically picked up the services and created necessary resources.

[1] https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with an alternative option,

describe the targetgroupbinding -->

```
[centos@ip-10-0-68-81 ~]$ kubectl describe targetgroupbinding -n prod-env --kubeconfig=$prod | grep Target
Kind:         TargetGroupBinding
  Target Group ARN:  arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:123456789098:targetgroup/k8s-prodenv-prodadmi-873264jwesa/87432kjfhkjds
  Target Type:       instance
```

And taken the arn of the Target Group, and used targetgroupbinding api to create the additional targetgroupbinding, which works for me;

```
apiVersion: elbv2.k8s.aws/v1beta1
kind: TargetGroupBinding
metadata:
  name: k8s-uat-test-1
  namespace: "uat-env"
  labels:
    k8s/environment: staging
spec:
  serviceRef:
    name: uat-test-service
    port: 3002
  targetGroupARN: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:123456789098:targetgroup/k8s-prodenv-prodadmi-873264jwesa/87432kjfhkjds
```

Comment: I am facing something a bit similar in the sense that the targets are not registered with the Target Group. But for me the TargetGroupBindings are not available as well.
Since the ALB is supposed to create the target group bindings itself, and there are no errors in the ALB pod logs, I am wondering how to debug this?

Comment: @Radioactive, yes, so what I suggest here, is just use the above method to bind the target

Comment: Hmm.. So you need to manuall bind the target everytime when new node added to the cluster?

Comment: @Turbo, It's a one-time activity, seems it's not fixed yet. If you delete the load balancer, yes you have to bind again manually.

Comment: I am on the latest chart version of 1.6.2
And yet facing the same issue, albeit with karpenter created nodes, eks managed group are getting attached, but not karpenter created

Answer (score -1):

You need give permissions at security group level creating rules that allow traffic from the loadBalancer IP to the node group security groups in order to have all tcp traffic to any port, try with that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).